# Customizing Iphone Keyboard

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to customize the iphone keyboard? Say I want the number pad with a comma button and a period button added to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a custom IME (Input Method) which is not directly supported in iOS (true custom IMEs have been developed, but require jailbreak). You can create a custom view, but just for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of iOS 3.2. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106875/custom-iphone-keyboard-for-sdk-4-ios4-os/3106910#3106910). You may not be able to edit the default keyboard, but it's not difficult to reproduce with your own view.